# Um método consegue acessar as propriedades do objeto a que pertence quando armazenado através de um delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, dicionário, delegate

Estou construindo um dicionário do seguinte tipo: `<string, delegate>`, que acessará um método pertencente a um objeto da seguinte classe:

```
class Example{

   public int Power { get; set; }
   public int Defense { get; set; }

   public void Method(){

      Console.WriteLine("Power: " + Power + " Defense: " + Defense);

   }

}
```

Como visto, o método depende das propriedades do objeto da classe, pois tem que acessar o `Power` e o `Defense`. Se eu armazenar o método, através de um `delegate` no dicionário e rodá-lo a partir de um `Dicionario["string"]();` ele conseguirá acessar as propriedades do objeto a que o método pertence? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um método acessado através de um `delegate` não é diferente de qualquer outro método, desde que o acesso seja feito através de um objeto válido para aquele tipo pode acessar tudo o que é público sem problemas, e se o acesso for interno mais ainda, aí pode acessar até o que é privado. Claro que se não tiver um objeto do tipo `Example` não poderá acessar, mas isso vale independente de estar usando um `delegate` ou não. O que está mostrando acessa internamente, então nem deveria ser uma questão. O método não sabe como ele é chamado, por isso nem importa se é `delegate` ou não. Nesse caso específico não vejo problema no que está fazendo, a não ser que tenha feito algo não mostrado na pergunta.